# PID recv: short read in CRIU

Tags: migration

I am receiving `PID recv: short read` error while using lazy pages migration with CRIU.

At the source, I run the following command:

`memhog -r1000 64m`

`cd /tmp/dump sudo -H -E criu dump -t $(pidof memhog) -D /tmp/dump --lazy-pages --address 10.237.23.102 --port 1234 --shell-job --display-stats -vvvv -o d.log`

Then, in a separate terminal on the source machine itself:

`scp -r /tmp/dump/ dst:/tmp/`

Now, on the destination machine I start the daemon:

`cd /tmp/dump criu lazy-pages --page-server --address $(gethostip -d src) --port 1234 --display-stats -vvvvv`

And finally, the restore command:
`cd /tmp/dump criu restore -D /tmp/dump/ --shell-job --lazy-pages -vvvv --display-stats -o restore.log -vvvv`

The error is thrown by the lazy server daemon on the destination machine.

Furthermore, it works fine for the `memhog` installed from `numactl`. However, it does not if I build it from the source.

Any suggestions for solving this will be appreciated.

::Update:: Solved. See answer

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue:

I was building them separately on two different machines due to which their "build-id" was not matching. Solution: Build on one machine and then just `scp` it over to the other machine.